# How do I code the individual in to an lme4 nested model?

Tags: r

Okay, I have students in classrooms in schools. I want to know if test score number depends on your school.

my basic model is:

```
basemodel <- lmer(test ~ schoolnumber +
     (1 | schoolnumber/classnumber), data=mydata)
```

Do I want to try and add in the student level?

Doesn't work:

```
model1 <- lmer(test ~ schoolnumber + 
    (1 | schoolnumber/classnumber/ studentID), data=ED)
```

Doesn't work:

```
model2 <- lmer(test ~ schoolnumber + 
(1 | schoolnumber/classnumber) +( 1 |studentID), data=ED)
```

Doesn't work:

```
model3 <- lmer(test ~ schoolnumber + 
(1 + studentID | schoolnumber/classnumber), data=ED)

model4 <- lmer(test ~ schoolnumber + studentID + 
(1 | schoolnumber/classnumber), data=ED)
```

When I add student ID it says

```
Warning message:
In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue
 - Rescale variables?
```

Also my current `test` score is a standardised score taken from raw scores, then z scores then linear transformation (standard scores);  `100 + 15(z)`.

Am I okay to use these linear transformed scores or should I be using something else? I've seen code elsewhere saying to use scale()?

Comment: I believe `schoolnumber` should be a factor. Did you make sure it is one? Then you don't need `schoolnumber` in the random effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Roland says, if `schoolnumber` is categorical/a factor variable, then your first model should fail:

```
~ schoolnumber + (1 | schoolnumber/classnumber)
```

includes `schoolnumber` as both a fixed categorical predictor and as a random effects grouping variable. `~ (1|schoolnumber/classnumber)` would make more sense.

If you get rid of `schoolnumber` as a fixed effect predictor, then

```
~ (1 | schoolnumber/classnumber) + (1|studentID)
```

*should* work.  I wouldn't recommend adding `studentID` as a fixed effect.

I'm assuming that students are labeled uniquely, i.e. that there isn't a student `1A57` in school number 1 and a different student `1A57` in school number 2 ...

How large is your data set at each level (observations, students, classes, schools)?  I'm guessing that students are nested within schools but crossed among classes, i.e. each student is in only one school but in more than one class.  As long as you have students labeled uniquely, it won't matter as much how you specify the model.